# community.general.xml: I can't figure out the xpath I need

Tags: xml, ansible

Using the Ansible module `community.general.xml`, I am attempting to populate attribute values, delete existing children and add my own. I can't get past identifying the correct xpath given the file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns="http://www.pulseway.com/linuxconfig">
  <Account Username="" Password="" UseCustomServer="false" CustomServerAddress="" Token=""/>
  <ComputerInformation Name="MyLittleServer" Group="Linux"/>
  <MonitoredServices>
    <Service Name="chrony.service" DisplayName="Chrony" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSTEMD" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="false" Enabled="false"/>
    <Service Name="firewalld.service" DisplayName="Firewalld" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSTEMD" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="false" Enabled="false"/>
    <Service Name="postfix.service" DisplayName="Postfix" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSTEMD" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="false" Enabled="true"/>
    <Service Name="sshd.service" DisplayName="SSHD" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSTEMD" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="false" Enabled="true"/>
  </MonitoredServices>
</config>
```

These are snippets of the tasks I intend to use, but I fail to identify xpath. I'm completely ignorant on XML.

```yaml
  - name: Set the Password
    community.general.xml:
      path: /etc/pulseway/config.xml
      xpath: /Account[@Username=""]
      attribute: Password
      value: "SecretSquirrel"
      state: present

  - name: Remove all children from the 'MonitoredServices' element
    community.general.xml:
      path:  /etc/pulseway/config.xml
      xpath: /config/MonitoredServices/*
      state: absent

  - name: Add Services to the 'MonitoredServices' element
    community.general.xml:
      path:  /etc/pulseway/config.xml
      xpath: /config/MonitoredServices/
      add_children:
      - Service Name: '"chronyd.service" DisplayName="ChronyD" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSTEMD" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="true" Enabled="true"'
      - Service Name: '"firewalld.service" DisplayName="FirewallD" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSTEMD" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="true" Enabled="true"'
      - Service Name: '"postfix.service" DisplayName="Postfix" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSTEMD" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="true" Enabled="true"'
      - Service Name: '"sshd.service" DisplayName="SSHD" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSTEMD" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="true" Enabled="true"'
```

Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem is that your XML document sets a default namespace, which means it doesn't have an element named `Account`. It has an element named `Account` *in the `http://www.pulseway.com/linuxconfig` namespace*...so you need to provide a [`namespaces`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xml_module.html#parameter-namespaces) dictionary as part of your module invocation.

That gets us:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Set the Password
    community.general.xml:
      path: config.xml
      namespaces:
        pulseway: http://www.pulseway.com/linuxconfig
      xpath: "/pulseway:config/pulseway:Account[@User='']"
      attribute: Password
      value: "SecretSquirrel"
      state: present

  - name: Remove all children from the 'MonitoredServices' element
    community.general.xml:
      path:  config.xml
      namespaces:
        pulseway: http://www.pulseway.com/linuxconfig
      xpath: /pulseway:config/pulseway:MonitoredServices/*
      state: absent

  - name: Add Services to the 'MonitoredServices' element
    community.general.xml:
      path:  config.xml
      namespaces:
        pulseway: http://www.pulseway.com/linuxconfig
      xpath: /pulseway:config/pulseway:MonitoredServices
      add_children:
      - Service:
          Name: "chronyd.service"
          DisplayName: "ChronyD"
          IsDaemon: "true"
          DaemonType: "SYSTEMD"
          Path: ""
          StartParameters: ""
          CanBeStopped: "true"
          Enabled: "true"
      - Service:
          Name: "firewalld.service"
          DisplayName: "FirewallD"
          IsDaemon: "true"
          DaemonType: "SYSTEMD"
          Path: ""
          StartParameters: ""
          CanBeStopped: "true"
          Enabled: "true"
```

Running the above on your example data produces:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<config xmlns="http://www.pulseway.com/linuxconfig">
  <Account Username="" Password="" UseCustomServer="false" CustomServerAddress="" Token=""/>
  <ComputerInformation Name="MyLittleServer" Group="Linux"/>
  <MonitoredServices>
    <Service Name="chronyd.service" DisplayName="ChronyD" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSTEMD" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="true" Enabled="true"/><Service Name="firewalld.service" DisplayName="FirewallD" IsDaemon="true" DaemonType="SYSTEMD" Path="" StartParameters="" CanBeStopped="true" Enabled="true"/></MonitoredServices>
<Account User="" Password="SecretSquirrel"/></config>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. All errors gone. Confirmed your changes work as you describe. I'm curious if I can replace the Account line instead of adding a new one? Specially since I need to populate multiple fields.

Comment: You're currently *modifying* the `Account` element, but if you want to replace it you could follow the same delete/add model you're using with the `MonitoredServices` element.

Comment: Ah, saw the problem. Your examples were using "User" for last element, actual case it's "Username". Thanks for your help. Works great.